# List the elements of $\langle\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ in $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and in $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\times)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> List the elements of  $\langle\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ in $(\mathbb{Q},+)$ and in 
>   $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\times)$.

where $\mathbb{Q}^*:=\mathbb{Q}\setminus\{0\}$

My attempt:

Well, I know that $\langle a\rangle=\{a^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\}$, so $\langle \dfrac{1}{2}\rangle=\left\{\left( \frac{1}{2}\right)^n:n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$

Well, for $(\mathbb{Q},+), \langle\frac{1}{2}\rangle= n\cdot \frac{1}{2}$, since the group is under addition, so the elements are:

$$\left\{\ldots,-\frac{3}{2},-1,-\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{2},1,\frac{3}{2},\ldots\right\}$$

As for $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\times), \langle \frac{1}{2}\rangle=\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$ the group is under multiplication so the elements are:

$$\left\{\ldots,8,4,2,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{4},\frac{1}{8},\ldots\right\}$$

I was just wondering if this was correct.

Comment: Yes, that is essentially correct

Comment: In $(\mathbb{Q}^*,\times)$, you need $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{0}=1$ included. Every group needs an identity element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your enumeration for $\left(\mathbb{Q}, +\right)$ is correct. In a group whose operation is addition, you must consider all multiples of the generator, including inverses (negative values).

However, in the second example of $\left(\mathbb{Q}^{*}, \times \right)$, you forgot the case of $\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^{0}=1$. A group with an operation of multiplication implies that you need to take all powers of the generator, including inverses (reciprocals). Thus, the generator raised to the $0$th power must be considered. Additionally, every group must have an identity element. Since the operation is multiplication, the group needs the multiplicative identity, which is $1$. So, the second example — $\left(\mathbb{Q}^{*}, \times \right)$ — requires that $1$ be an element.